# Constructor overload

Tags: java, android, constructor

This is my class:

```
public class DateTime {

private int hours;
private int minutes;
private int seconds;
private int day;
private int month;
private int year;



public DateTime(int hours, int minutes, int seconds) {


    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);

    this(hours,minutes,seconds,day,month,year); //Error: call to this must be first statement in constructor java

}


public DateTime(int hours, int minutes, int seconds, int day, int month, int year) {

    this.hours = hours;
    this.minutes = minutes;
    this.seconds = seconds;
    this.day = day;
    this.month = month;
    this.year = year;
}
}
```

I wish to overload the constructor with this logic, 
But I get error:

 **"call to this must be first statement in constructor java"**,

 can you please suggest a solution?

Comment: You can simply call `this()` first and set you `day`, `month`, `year` afterwards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several solutions...

0) inline the constructor call and set hours minutes and seconds directly, it's not worth the trouble

1) use an intermediary constructor

```
public DateTime(int hours, int minutes, int seconds) {
    this(hours, minutes, seconds, Calendar.getInstance());
}
private DateTime(int hours, int minutes, int seconds, Calendar c) {
    this(hours,minutes,seconds,c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH),c.get(Calendar.MONTH),c.get(Calendar.YEAR));
}
```

2) use a factory method instead of constructor

```
public static DateTime newDateTime(int hours, int minutes, int seconds) {
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    return new DateTime(hours,minutes,seconds,day,month,year);
}
```

3) invert the dependency (day month year get set twice)

```
public DateTime(int hours, int minutes, int seconds, int day, int month, int year) {
    this(hours, minutes, seconds);
    this.day = day;
    this.month = month;
    this.year = year;
}
```

4) delegate to method instead of constructor

```
public DateTime(int hours, int minutes, int seconds) {
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    set(hours,minutes,seconds,day,month,year);
}
public DateTime(int hours, int minutes, int seconds, int day, int month, int year) {
    set(hours,minutes,seconds,day,month,year);
}
private final void set(int hours, int minutes, int seconds, int day, int month, int year) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

As 'this()' should be the first one to be called by constructor. Then there is only solution. You can use like this:

```
public class DateTime {

private int hours;
private int minutes;
private int seconds;
private int day;
private int month;
private int year;



public DateTime(int hours, int minutes, int seconds) {

Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
this.day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
this.month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
this.year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
this.hours = hours;
this.minutes = minutes;
this.seconds = seconds;

}
}
```

Now i think this will work fine.